# Как сохранить данные формы после перехода на другую страницу?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii2

Есть форма на странице, без `submmit` кнопки!

Как можно сохранять данные с формы, когда страница перезагружается или пользователь переходит на другую страницу?

Работаю с `yii2`. Возможно есть готовый `jquery` плагин для этого?

Пробовал делать `$('#form').submit()` результат вроде есть (данные сохраняются), но когда переходит в контроллер где сохраняется форма - нужно куда-то редиректить или переходит на пустую страницу браузера! Возможно можно сделать чтоб контроллер просто выполнялся и ничего не возвращал?

**Или как лучше это реализовать ?**

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов масса, самый простой и топорный это сохранить данные в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
c помощью Jquery или чистого Js. или использовать более старые методы, сохранить в куки например

Comment: А потом в бд сохранять ? После завершения сессии ?

Comment: зачем в бд? храните в локальном хранилище браузера клиента если у вас это не очень нужные промежуточные данные. если они вам для чего то еще нужны записывайте в бд после необходимых изменений,
а так  localStorage хранится на стороне клиента бесконечно долго (до очистки юзером браузера) или до того как вы их удалите оттуда

Comment: это можно сделать без нажатый кнопок ? Просто нужно сохранять форму юзера в бд после редактирования юзером формы, но при этом не должно быть кнопок! 
А можно с помощью js обработать переход на другую страницу или перезагрузку страницы  ?

Comment: можно, но чтобы получить полноценный ответ будьте добры опишите полностью проблему что откуда приходит что куда уходит зачем это нужно делать чего вы хотите добиться каков должен быть результат...
без этих уточнений вам куда полезнее будет пойти и прочитать основы пхп и js